# Manipulating a list to make it nested

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have a long list, where the elements are of this kind `{x,y,g,a1,a2,a3}` and I want to extract some sublists with which I can make plots or manipulate the elements.

For instance, if I want to make a `ContourPlot` that has `x` and `y` as the cartesian axes and `g` as the "third" axis that creates the contour, I would really love to have my entries rearranged in a **nested way** as `{{x,y},g}`, from which I could easily create an `InterpolatingFunction` like:

```
newlistTEMP = Interpolation[nestedlist, InterpolationOrder->2];
gfunc[x_,y_] := newlistTEMP[x,y];
```

However, I am failing at finding a clever way to rearrange the elements of my list into the desired nested list form.
The best I can do is to extract a sublist like:

```
sublist = Cases[list, {x_, y_, g_, _, _, _} :> {x, y, g}];
```

but after this I am stuck.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I don’t understand the problem, I’m afraid. Can you just put `{{x, y}, g}` on the right hand-side in `Cases`?

Comment: Or `data2 = {#[[1 ;; 2]], #[[3]]} & /@ data`

Comment: @C.E. no, it does not give a nested list.

Comment: @Lele I posted my approach as an answer with an output example, in case we are simply talking past each other. If that output is not what you mean by nested list, please explain what you mean by nested list.

Answer (score 6):

Here is one way:

```
list = ConstantArray[Range[6], 10];
Cases[list, {x_, y_, g_, _, _, _} :> {{x, y}, g}]
```

> `{{{1, 2}, 3}, {{1, 2}, 3}, {{1, 2}, 3}, {{1, 2}, 3}, {{1, 2},    3}, {{1, 2}, 3}, {{1, 2}, 3}, {{1, 2}, 3}, {{1, 2}, 3}, {{1, 2}, 3}}`

Comment: Ok, this does the trick. It didn't work in the first place for an error of mine. However, when I try to interpolate the data, it returns this error message: 
`Interpolation::udeg: Interpolation on unstructured grids is currently only supported for InterpolationOrder->1 or InterpolationOrder->All. Order will be reduced to 1.`
This is strange, usually it should be possible to create a function that interpolates the coordinates `{{x1,y1},f[x1,y1]}, {{x2,y2},f[x2,y2]}, ...` with the interpolation order that I wish.

Answer (score 3):

```
{x, y, g, a, b, c} /. {x_, y_, g_, next___} :> f1[{{x, y}, g}, f2@next]
```

and replace `f1`, `f2` by whatever you need.

Answer (score 3):

```
list = Array[Range[5] &, 3];
```

Using [MapApply](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapApply.html) (new in 13.1)

```
MapApply[{{#1, #2}, #3} &, list]
```

{{{1, 2}, 3}, {{1, 2}, 3}, {{1, 2}, 3}}

Using [TakeList](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TakeList.html) (new in 11.2)

```
FlattenAt[2] @ TakeList[#, {2, 1}] & /@ list
```

{{{1, 2}, 3}, {{1, 2}, 3}, {{1, 2}, 3}}

Answer (score 2):

Using `Join` and `Transpose`:

```
list = ConstantArray[Range[6], 10];
Transpose[{list[[All, {1, 2}]], list[[All, 3]]}]

(*{{{1, 2}, 3}, {{1, 2}, 3}, {{1, 2}, 3}, {{1, 2}, 3}, {{1, 2}, 
  3}, {{1, 2}, 3}, {{1, 2}, 3}, {{1, 2}, 3}, {{1, 2}, 3}, {{1, 2}, 3}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}};
```

---

Grabbing the @eldo's list and using `ReplaceList`:

```
ReplaceList[list, {___, {a__}, ___} :> {{a}[[;; 2]], {a}[[3]]}]

(*{{{1, 2}, 3}, {{1, 2}, 3}, {{1, 2}, 3}}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
MapThread[{{#1, #2}, #3} &, Transpose@list]

(* {{{1, 2}, 3}, {{1, 2}, 3}, {{1, 2}, 3}} *)
```

---

```
list = Array[Range[5] &, 3]; // @eldo
```